# Passing Python variable to Javascript with Webapp2/Jinja2

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2, webapp2

I've researched this answer and haven't found a way to do this using webapp2. I need to pass a variable from my Python code into my Javascript code. I understand how to pass variables into my HTML using Jinja2 but I am stumped on how they can then be used in Javascript.

This is what I have put in the `head` of my HTML page:

`<meta id="trello_id" data-name="{{ trello_id }}">`

And I have this line in my Javascript:

`var trelloId = $('#trello_id').data();`

It doesn't work however printing `trelloId` to console just prints null. What is the best way to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

Use `content` instead of `data-name`. In your case:

`<meta id="trello_id" content="{{ trello_id }}">`

For more information, on how to use the `meta` tag you can look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) page.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Javascript code to and see if this works:

```
var trelloId = $('#trello_id').data('name');
```